# How to download a specific file type from all subdirectories of an FTP server?

Tags: python, download, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to download all `.laz` files from the FTP host `gis.arkansas.gov` (more details [here](http://gis.arkansas.gov/?page_id=7813)). Looking at the [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html) documentation, I see that I can list all of the directories in the FTP server:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('gis.arkansas.gov')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('Elevation')
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

---

Which yields the following:

```
>>> ftp.retrlines('LIST')
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 AGFC_RAW
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 AR State Parks
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Bayou Meto Lidar Phase I
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Bayou_Meto_Watershed
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Beaver_Lake
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Beaver_Tailwater
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Black_River
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 May 30 09:24 Blue_Mountain
# ... And so on ...
```

How can I download all of the files with a .laz extension from each of these directories (some directories do not contain .laz files)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic.

You have to:

- recurse into the subdirectories,
- list their contents one by one,
- filter all `.laz` files,
- call `retrbinary` for each.